# EDIT: Delegate/Function for Roles - [Authorize(x=> x.Role == Role.Admin && x.Role == Role.Client)]

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-mvc-2, attributes

`[Authorize(Role=Role.Admin, Role.Client)]` does not work yet, `[Authorize(Role="Admin,Client")]` works, I want to pass in strongly typed objects as I have them defined, does anyone know how?

I dont want to be hitting the database multiple times so something like:

```
[Authorize(Role=Role.Admin)] 
[Authorize(Role= Role.Client)] 
public ActionResult Something()
{

}
```

Is not ok for me...

EDIT:

Ok... so the previous question has been asked before, but I have amended, How do I create this as a delegate or function? I want to select one or more roles? Is this possible?

I could do:

```
[Authorize(x=> x.Role == Role.Admin && x.Role == Role.Client)]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non-string role names in ASP.NET MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828444/non-string-role-names-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Sorry I did not see that, yes this is a duplicate...

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this blog post on how to implement a custom authorize annotation that takes an array of strongly typed role objects:

http://geekswithblogs.net/tyarmer/archive/2010/02/25/strongly-typed-roles-in-mvc-with-authorize-attribute.aspx