# MVC configure Authorize Roles value and strongly typed role

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authorize-attribute

In order to authorize a controller for a particular role, following attribute is required on the controller class:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "SampleRole")]
```

This requires role name to be hard-coded on the Controller and does not seem to be a flexible solution.
My question is that, it is possible to specify value for that role in the web.config and using that key in the controller?

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="SampleRoleKey" value="SampleRole" /> 
    ...
</appSettings>
```

And in the controller,

```
[Authorize(Roles = "SampleRoleKey")]
```

Another question is that, can we use strongly typed role to authorize the controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a static class with public const-s:

```
public static class Roles
{
    public const string SampleRoleKey = "SampleRole";
}
```

Create a custom MyAuthorizeAttribute derived from AuthorizeAttribute to have a property which can handle an array of strings and then:

```
[MyAuthorize(MyRoles = new[]{ Roles.SampleRoleKey }]
```

Comment: thanks, that was helpful. i found another solution using enums [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828444/non-string-role-names-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Sorry i've fixed the answer (it is just an example).

Comment: @user1014639 - that was so helpful you couldn't give Peter Kiss an vote?