# Allowing users to view parts of webpage based on their Windows domain login

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, kerberos

I am currently working on a small, simple project. I have a list of users stored in a database like so:

```
Id, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNo, DomainAC
```

I have displayed this information on an ASP.NET webpage and am unsure how I can progress now. I now wish to:

- Test the `Domain Account` field of the table in the database against
  the current users Windows Domain login.
- Allow them to edit their details only if they are the same user.
- Ensure this is secure.

  ```
  <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.Employees>>" %> 

   <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">

    Index

  </asp:Content> 

  <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server"> 

      <h2>Index</h2> 

      <table>

          <tr>

              <th></th>

              <th>

                  Id

              </th>

              <th>

                  FirstName

              </th>

              <th>

                  Last Name

              </th>

              <th>

                  Phone No.

              </th>

               <th>

                  Domain A/C

              </th>

          </tr> 

      <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>



          <tr>

              <td>

                  <%= Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) %> |

                  <%= Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id })%>

              </td>

              <td>

                  <%= Html.Encode(item.Id) %>

              </td>

              <td>

                  <%= Html.Encode(item.FirstName) %>

              </td>

              <td>

                  <%= Html.Encode(item.LastName) %>

              </td>

              <td>

                  <%= Html.Encode(item.PhoneNo) %>

              </td>

              <td>

                  <%= Html.Encode(item.DomainAC) %>

              </td>
          </tr>



      <% } %> 

      </table> 

      <p>

          <%= Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create") %>

      </p> 

  </asp:Content>
  ```

How can I now make it so that the "Edit" function above only works if the domain a/c matches your current login, unless you're logged in as the user "Admin", then you can edit everything.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simon,

You tag the question with asp.net-mvc, so I will give a quick example based on that.

In your controller you can decorate either the entire controller, or just the action with the [Authorize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) attribute. This means that you can explicity allow only users within certain [Roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k850zwb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to have access to the function.

By way of a quick example:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "AdminRole, CreditAdvisorRole")]
public ActionResult Edit()
{
    var viewModel = _shopService.ShopIndex();
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

So, that example would only allow users defined in the roles of "AdminRole" and "CreditAdvisorRole" to access the functionality. This of course is inbuilt behaviour and at some point, you will hit the limitations of this approach. At this point, then you can move on and create your own overrides on the AuthorizeAttribute.

Also, as you are not using Forms authentication, you will have to explore wider options on this, but the override may be able to guide you on that path (re aquiring info via active directory and applying a similar roles based logic).

There are a few good examples of that here on SO. This one in particulat took my fancy (see JohnnyO's answer):

[Non-string role names in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828444/non-string-role-names-in-asp-net-mvc)

enjoy..

Comment: Thanks for this; this has gotten me started and now I will be able to post up a few more specific questions in the next few hours!

Comment: glad to have opened up a few avanues simon. will check out your future questions... ciao--->